# What is the VB equivalent of the following code snippet?

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    settings.Indent = true;
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
settings.Indent = True
Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings)

End Using
```

You can use this for conversions:

http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
settings.Indent = True
```

Not sure on the last line though.